# Cancelling a $document event listener in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a created a listener to catch the `keypress` events using `$document.on` and it works fine . The problem here is I want the listener to be active only when a particular modal is open and when its closed the listener should be cancelled .The problem else is that even after the modal is closed the listener would listen to the events and since I have an `event.preventDefault()` even entering in the input box then wouldn't work .

Below is a directive I am using:

```
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            choice: '=detectKeypair',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            listener = $document.on('keydown keypress', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $timeout(function () {
                  //pressed keys are available here
                })
            });

            scope.$on('modal.closing', function () {
                // listener();
                $document.off('keydown keypress',function(){console.log('closed')});
                console.log("Closing modal inside directive");
            })
        }
    }
```

As you can see I have assigned the listener to a variable and calling it on the modals close event . Unfortunately that did not work , I event tried to cancel the listener by calling `$document.off` and passing the events .

Even that refused to work . Help !! ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cancel an event listener it is mandatory that you pass the same function you have passed to create the listener .

```
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            listener = $document.on('keydown keypress', keyboardListener);

            function keyboardListener(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $timeout(function () {
                   //got the keys here
                })
            }

            // On closing the modal , cancel the listener
            scope.$on('modal.closing', function () {
                $document.off('keydown keypress', keyboardListener);
            })
        }
```

That worked .